# How do I disable the 'My Aptana' tab from opening when I open eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

The 'My Aptana' tab takes forever to load, and I never look at it, I always close it asap, I've looked many times but have been unable to discover a way to disable this tab from opening.. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy :)

Window -> Preferences -> Aptana -> My Aptana -> Message center

and select "never display after start up"

Answer (score 0):

Or in the Aptana 2 for Eclipse plugin:

Window -> Preferences -> Aptana -> Startup page